# Login Screen UI changes

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I have done my login screen with the theme Theme.Holo.Light, and I got my edit fields as shown below in image 1 but want to change it as image 2. Any help will be appreciated.

changes to make -
in my current UI it has only light blue underline, i want to change it to a box shape with white borders.
Currently im toasting the error message but i want my edit field border to change as in the image 2
check box border is white but its not visible much, wanna make it white thike border

image 1

[image]

image2

[image]

my activity class code

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    EditText emailET;
    EditText pwdET;
    String email;
    String password;
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_user);
        pwdET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_pwd);
//      pwdET.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    String email = emailET.getText().toString();
                    String password = pwdET.getText().toString();

                    if (Utility.isNotNull(email) && Utility.isNotNull(password)) {

                        if (Utility.validate(email)) {

                            if (emailET.getText().toString().equals(email)
                                    && pwdET.getText().toString()
                                    .equals(password)) {
                                CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_rememberme);
                                if (ch.isChecked())
                                    rememberMe(email, password); // save email

                            }

                            new LoginAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this).execute(
                                    email, password);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Asynctask started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();

                        }
                        // When Email is invalid
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please enter valid email",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    // When any of the Edit View control left blank
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please fill the form, don't leave any field blank",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }

            }
        });
```

my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btlogin"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ch_rememberme"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#188e04"
        android:onClick="doLogin"
        android:text="LOGIN NOW"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ch_rememberme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btlogin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_pwd"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Remember login information"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_pwd"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_user"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txt_pwd"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_pwd"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make a custom xml file using `rectangle` shape in `drawable` folder and apply it as a background to your `EditText`.

Comment: Hi do you have the images for that ? because if you apply theme it will show  ui with default images.. things which you wants it is possible using shapes and for check box it will required images.

Comment: @PiyushGupta is it possible to create shape for the checkbox which he wants.. in second image he mentioned ..if possible thn pls share it..

Comment: Yeah it can be. Check these http://androidexample.com/Custom_Checkbox_With_The_Use_Of_Selectors_And_Shapes/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=80&aaid=104 , http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-custom-checkbox-in-your-android-app/. But i suggested to you use two different images for checkbox. one for checked and another for unchecked.

Comment: @PiyushGupta but its not with the checkedmarked in shape ...

Comment: @user1140237 But have you read last comment line after that?

Comment: @PiyushGupta cool ... i asked because quesion is for the whole ui... and u mentioned in you comment that using shape its possible(lttr u edited it) .. no issue.. will check it.. thanks..

Comment: @user1140237 Its Okay dude. Np.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta Hi it worked, how to change the text colour to red when its wrong password or wrong email

Comment: `EditText` has its own property. You can use `edittext.setError("Wrong Password");` when there is a wrong password.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta xml file doesn't allow to use that, can u tell me how to do that please. do i need to use android:

Comment: Not in xml you need to use in your java class file.

Comment: ok thanks, ill work on it

Answer (score 0):

You have to define some styles and shape in your xml and use this xml as your login screen edit text background.

your **login screen** xml

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btlogin"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ch_rememberme"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#188e04"
        android:onClick="doLogin"
        android:text="LOGIN NOW"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ch_rememberme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btlogin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_pwd"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Remember login information"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_pwd"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:background="@drawable/loginstyle"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_user"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txt_pwd"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_pwd"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loginstyle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ea2628" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Loginstyle.xml** place this file in your drawable folder

```css
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
 
   <!--  view background color -->
    <solid
        
        android:color="#040404" >
    </solid>
 
    <!-- view border color and width -->
    <stroke
         android:width="1px"
         
        android:color="#ea2628" >
    </stroke>
 
   
    <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3px"
        android:bottomRightRadius="3px"
        android:topLeftRadius="3px"
        android:topRightRadius="3px"   >
    </corners>
</shape>
```

Here i have given single color for both text view, use another file for different color, see comments to change colors

Comment: I want to change the text colour to red only if the username or password is wrong

Comment: To do this you have to do programatical implementation like this TextView et = new TextView(activity);
et.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white); Do this when your password is wrong

Comment: this makes the border red but this is not what i want. what i want is look at image 2, when im typing the email and password it shows white letter and white border. once i entered wrong password or email it should turn into red. ill post my code as well, will u b able to help me with it

Comment: check my updated answer, if it worked i will definitly vote u, no doubts about that

Comment: why are you asking exact program

Comment: write another login style xml, when your password is wrong load another login style like EditText et= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
et.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loginstyle2);